# Adding a UIButton as a subview, but it does not display.

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

My button won't display. Does anyone know why?

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    CTrial *tt = [CTrial alloc];
    [tt hellothere:self]; 
}


/////////////////////////////
#import "CTrial.h"
@implementation CTrial


- (void) hellothere: (UIViewController*) ss
{
    UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn2 setTag:200];
    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(menuSetup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,200)];
    [ss.view addSubview:btn2];
}
```

I have tried "id"

```
- (id) hellothere: (UIViewController*) ss
```

with the return but still nothing

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CButton.h"

@interface CTrial : //UIView

-(void) menuSetup:(UIButton*) btn;
- (id) hellothere: (UIViewController*) ss;
//- (void) hellothere: (UIViewController*) ss;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

You usually use `UIButtonTypeCustom` if you want to display a custom button, for example displaying an image instead of the classical button, but since you are not assigning any image to the button it's simply transparent, that is why you cannot see it.

Besides use

```
CTrial *tt = [[CTrial alloc] init];
```

`alloc` simply allocate the memory, does not initialize your object

Comment: it is still just a black background screen... if I remove the CTrial instantiation it is a gray background

Comment: what do you have to inherit?  ... UIView, can it be nothing... otherwise you can't "alloc" ?

Comment: in the header file:  @interface CTrial : UIView   <-- ??

Comment: @jdl I don't know what `CTrial` is and why do you need it so I cannot answer, it actually depends on your needs. For the code that I see it could be also a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: I am eventually trying to subclass a button with drawn graphics on it and more.  So I try something simple to start.